# LINQ to MySQL - what is the best option?

Tags: mysql, linq

Has anyone used any of the utilities out there for LINQ to MySQL? Do you know which one is best?

So far I know of LINQ for NHibernate, and DBLinq

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is also LINQ to LLBLGEN, which then can support many, many databases.

From [LLBLGEN's Feature Page](http://www.llblgen.com/)

> Support for SQL Server (MSDE, SQL Server
>   7/2000/2005/Express, SQL CE 2.0, 3.0,
>   3.5), SQL Server CE Desktop (New!), Oracle (Oracle 8i / 9i /10g),
>   PostgreSQL 7.4+/8.x, Firebird 1.x /
>   2.x, IBM DB2 UDB (7.x/8.x/9.x), **MySQL (4.x, 5.x)**, Sybase Adaptive Server
>   Enterprise (ASE) (New!), Sybase SQL
>   iAnywhere (ASA) (New!) and MS Access
>   2000/XP/2003/2007

Answer (score 7):

There is also [Mindscape LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx), which works with MySQL amongst other databases, and has a LINQ provider.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, [LINQ to NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#Other_providers) will provide this sort of functionality as will the entity framework with a MySQL provider. I don't know of any other way of doing it as [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) was very much specific to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft has the most wonderful technologies ... if only they were only multi-latform and open source then it would be perfect :)

Comment: Practically Speaking Many of the programmers who powers open sources(including LINUX) are getting their daily bread from microsoft technologies. If there is no MS then there will be no (without payment) developers for opensources.

Answer (score 4):

Try our MySQL-specific LINQ to SQL implementation. 
Overview is available [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/linq.html).

Comment: I'd like to reccomend Devart's linq to mysql (Linqconnect) tutorial: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/tutorial_linq.html Thanks for your job guys!