# How do I properly use LINQ with MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to MySQL - what is the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469100/linq-to-mysql-what-is-the-best-option)

I've been looking this up on Google for hours, but I haven't found anything conclusive. So far, I've seen a few paid options, an option with NHibernate, but most are marked as unstable or in production.

Is there a stable implementation of LINQ for MySQL?

Comment: Could be classified as a dupe, but time has moved on since that original post and there may be other solutions out there now.

Comment: I agree, Mark, odd that it didn't turn up in my searches. However, that question did not provide the answer I needed, unlike this one.

Comment: I love the fact this question, with an accepted answer not listed in any of the 'duplicates', is still closed as such.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) supports only Microsoft SQL Server. You could use [ADO.NET Entity Framework with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entity-framework.html). Here's a [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html).

Comment: I've been looking at that, but will that offer the same LINQ features LINQ to SQL provides? (deferred execution, LINQ converted to SQL)

Comment: Yes it provides those features.

Comment: For anyone looking to bind in asp.net: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-databinding-linq-entities.html

Comment: The links in this answer need to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

We use Devart [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) for LINQ-to-Oracle and have been very pleased.

They make [an equivalent **LINQ-to-MySQL provider** as well](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/), I'd definitely give it a look.

Comment: I've seen that one, but I'd rather not pay for it.

Comment: @Adra - There are multiple levels, [including a free version](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/editions.html) but you should really specify "free only" in your question if that's the case, comparatively the Devart stuff is *really* cheap.

Comment: +1 for the Devart Oracle drivers.  If the MySQL ones are of similar quality than this is definitely the direction to go in.

Comment: I thought I did specify free only by stating 'paid options' as something I didn't like, but I'll try to be more clear in the future.

Comment: @Arda - Thanks for making it clearer in the future, just a matter of perspective I suppose.  In case it helps at all, the way I read/construed your current question is: "I would consider a paid option in the absence of a suitable free option"