# mySQL + LINQ to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I've been looking around for a definitive answer as to how to use LINQ to SQL with mySQL but can't seem to come up with anything.  Does anyone have any experience / suggestions using the two together?  In particular, I would like to avoid using string SQL statements.

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to MySQL - what is the best option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469100/linq-to-mysql-what-is-the-best-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL isn't directly supported by Microsoft's LINQ to SQL provider, but there are several alternative ways you can use LINQ against MySQL.
Take a look at using [LINQ to nHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/16/Linq-for-NHibernate.aspx), or see [here](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) for LINQ providers against non-Microsoft databases.

Answer (score 0):

Now (as of 2015) you can use the Connector/NET provided by MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials.html