# how to Add background worker in database application

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am working on an application which keeps records of check ins and checkouts of the customer. i want to embed the background worker class in my project.

here is the situation:

I want  list of rooms to be upadted automatically on saving the information on the new room... for displaying room i am  using gridview and for adding new room i created a new form and add LINQ to SQL query code to save the information of new room.

kindly help me with this.. or suggest me something else.  how to implement it.. for you information and i am using LINQ to SQL class..

Technologies I am using:

Editor: Visual Studio2010
Language: C# 
back end Database in MYSQL Server 2008
using LINQtoSQL for creating connection with the data base

Comment: You need to give us more information about technologies you are using. Try to see the question from our point of view.

Comment: I have updated the description check it now. or for your ease i am posting here again

Editor: Visual Studio2010 Language: C# back end Database in MYSQL Server 2008 using LINQtoSQL for creating connection with the data base

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL + LINQ to SQL in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650817/mysql-linq-to-sql-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650817/mysql-linq-to-sql-in-c-sharp), the Linq-to-Sql does not provide access to MySQL database out-of-box, however, there are several workaround.