# Persistence layer migration

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql, orm

I have a project with implemented persistence layer (I've used LINQ to SQL). This application works with MS SQL Server. Customer wants to work with MySQL simultaneously. How can I use my LINQ classes with new database server? Is it possible? What can I use for this task decision?

David

Comment: you can see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469100/linq-to-mysql-what-is-the-best-option