# how to use LINQ to SQL with mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

How to use LINQ to SQL with MySQL.

I am having one project with C# (version 2010) and LINQ to SQL. Database is SQL.

I need to migrate the project to LINQ to MySQL and C# version 2010.

And also need to migrate existing SQL database to MySQL database.

I downloaded `DBLinq` but don't know how to use it in project.

Comment: Read the manual: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/Installation

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469100/linq-to-mysql-what-is-the-best-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is a provider for it (same as for SqlLite).

Take a look at the following links:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/e9fc6bc7-fbc6-44c4-b37b-4b4a83beaa3e
- http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

DBLinq should have everything you need though...

Answer (score 8):

LINQ to SQL is designed to work with Microsoft SQL Server only, as far as I know. If possible, you should migrate to Entity Framework or another DB-agnostic O/R-mapper.

Answer (score 2):

Check out 'LINQ to MySql' nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.MySql/

LINQ to MySql is a data access technology that provides a run-time infrastructure for managing relational data as objects.

This package includes a T4 template to generate data models for MySql database and references to the linq2db and MySql.Data nugets.