# SQL-Server alternative for linux in term of sql syntax

Tags: sql-server

Is there any database for linux, which SQL syntax is same as of SQL-Server? As SQL-Server is yet to be released for linux.

Comment: It is available now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to use LINQ To SQL with MySQL. .NET will take care of syntax. Your same code will work with sql server as well, by just making minute changes(which i understand as your concern). See this [how to use LINQ to SQL with mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388347/how-to-use-linq-to-sql-with-mysql)