# SqlException while Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

i am trying to use Linq to Sql technology, but encounter some problems.

Here is my simple code.

```
[Table]
    public class countries
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)] public int Id;
        [Column] public string Country;
        [Column] public int Continent;
    }
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string connection = "SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=advworks; UID=root; PWD=root;";

        DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(connect.connection);


        Table<countries> table = dataContext.GetTable<countries>();

        var query = from n in table
                    select n.Country;



        foreach (var item in query)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

I have MySql server with appropriate shema and table. The problem is that query generates this - `SELECT [t0].[Country] FROM [countries] AS [t0]`
but when i start the program `sqlexception` is thrown because of syntax error.

i have try to input - `SELECT [t0].[Country] FROM [countries] AS [t0]`
in my sql directly, and it worked only after i removed square brackets.

Why linq generates this square brackets? Or there is problem with my sql server?

Comment: Is it MySql or SqlServer? Those are two different products. The syntax of the generated query will work with SQL Server, but not with MySql.

Comment: Use  Entity Framework, Linq-To-Sql works with SQL-Server whereas EF works with [many databases including MySql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/).

Comment: I have mysql server. Is there way to generate appropriate sql syntax with Linq to Sql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use LINQ to SQL with mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388347/how-to-use-linq-to-sql-with-mysql)